# Playframework yaml set syntax

Tags: playframework, yaml, snakeyaml

Does PlayFramework have support for yaml sets? I have tried the formats specified by the snakeyaml [documentation](http://yaml.org/type/set.html) but only the first member of the set gets added to the set, the rest are ignored. Here are some examples of what I have tried.

```
groups:
   - &adminGroup !!my.package.UserGroup
    name: admin
    roles:
        - *adminRole
    users: !!set
        ? *adminUser 
        ? *adminUser2
```

Also tried
`users: [ *adminUser, *adminUser2 ]` and 
`users: !!set { *adminUser, *adminUser2 }`

Comment: Try to add a dash at the end, cf [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9173264/1205368). If that does not work you can try to use a list instead

Comment: I had previously tried it with a dash at the end but I get an exception "sequence entries are not allowed here"

Comment: And you tried using a list? BTW you are using Play 2.x right? I think Play 1 YAML uses a different syntax...

Comment: I'm using Play 2.2.3 and lists do work, its just that for this bean I need a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here was the syntax that worked for me
`users: 
    ? *adminUser
    ? *adminUser2`
The reason only the first user was being inserted into the Set was because the hash of the 2 objects were equal and so the second wouldn't get inserted, because to prevent duplicate items, the Set hashes the objects. I added a hashCode method to my users class and voila. Hope this helps someone in the future.